# the meta character in linux soft quoting

Tags: linux, shell, quoting

```
[root@Z ~]# echo \n
n
[root@Z ~]# echo "\n"
\n
[root@Z ~]# echo '\n'
\n
```

And

```
[root@Z ~]# echo '\\'
\\
[root@Z ~]# echo "\\"
\
[root@Z ~]# echo \\
\
```

What's the problem?

soft quoting can disable \ or not???

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you asking? Which of these confuses you?

Comment: According to the exception in soft quoting,the \ should be reserved function.but why run echo "\n" get \n  ,it's should be get n

Comment: Sorry,I get it.https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to interpret escape sequences many `echo` versions must be invoked with the argument -e as described by the POSIX specifications under "On XSI-conformant systems.. " in the page for `echo`. To circumvent this potential inconsistency instead use the more portable `printf` utility. Here are some examples:

Output an actual newline character:

```
printf "\n"
```

Output an uninterpreted "\n" character string:

```
printf "\\\n"
```

If you absolutely want to use `echo` still, you can pass it the `-e` option as follows:

Output an actual newline character:

```
echo -ne "\n"
```

Output an uninterpreted "\n" character string:

```
echo -n "\n"
```

Single ticks verse quotes have no bearing on the operation of escape sequences. The differentiation of single ticks verse quotes is primarily useful in regards to glob and variable expansion. And you will find that on some shells, namely some ash variants (dash) that the -e option is not supported, and instead the shell behaves as if -e is default. Again, to circumvent this potentially confusing and non-portable scenario use `printf`.